# Ray Workflows error: This event loop is already running

Tags: python, ray

I am using Ray Workflows and when I try to create a virtual actor or run a workflow I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

A snippet of the code that is creating the issue looks like this:

```
from ray import workflow

@workflow.virtual_actor
class ContextNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.context = {}

    def put(self, key, value):
        self.context[key] = value

    @workflow.virtual_actor.readonly
    def get(self, key):
        return self.context[key]

workflow.init()
context = ContextNode.get_or_create('context')
```

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It works well on my side. I'm using ray 1.8.

```
2021-11-03 16:16:10,573 INFO services.py:1270 -- View the Ray dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:8265
2021-11-03 16:16:12,871 INFO workflow_access.py:378 -- Initializing workflow manager...
2021-11-03 16:16:13,060 INFO execution.py:48 -- Workflow job created. [id="context", storage_url="file:///tmp/ray/workflow_data"]. Type: ACTOR_METHOD
(pid=17077) 2021-11-03 16:16:13,078 INFO workflow_access.py:185 -- run_or_resume: context, __main__.ContextNode.__init__,ObjectRef(cf0d7cd337b7cc3bffffffffffffffffffffffff0100000001000000)
(pid=17077) 2021-11-03 16:16:13,081 INFO workflow_access.py:194 -- Workflow job [id=context] started.
(pid=17076) 2021-11-03 16:16:13,209 INFO step_executor.py:255 -- Step status [RUNNING]  [context@__main__.ContextNode.__init__] [1/1]
(pid=17076) 2021-11-03 16:16:13,218 INFO step_executor.py:376 -- Step status [SUCCESSFUL]   [context@__main__.ContextNode.__init__]
```

If you are using workflow with python asyncio on a higher level, you probably want to give [nest-asyncio](https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/) a try. Simply call `nest_asyncio.apply()` in the place where workflow is used.

Inside workflow, asyncio is used to do operation on IO, and sometimes, it'll conflict with up layer libraries.

Comment: I think it was because I was in a jupyter notebook. When I put it in a python script it worked as well. Don't know why jupyter was causing issues.

Comment: Do you want to try this one https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/ ? I think maybe because workflow and juypter notebook is using the same asyncio thread.